# How to not print anything when inputed a blank in conditionals and for loops?

Tags: python

I know my title sounds a bit weird but please definitely take a look down:

```
available_things=["bike","smart tv","car","i-phone X"]
prices=[100,150,180,300] 
additionals=["smart phone","xbox","ps4","laptop","computer accessories"]

things=raw_input("\nWhat you wish to get:")
selected_additionals=[]
for val in range(0,3):
    selected_additionals.append(raw_input("Enter an additional item:"))

for selected_additional in selected_additionals: 
    if selected_additional not in additionals or selected_additional== " ":
        print("\nSorry we don't have "+str(selected_additional)+"\nBut we will change it to a gift")
```

You can run my code here: https://repl.it/repls/WrySuburbanRabbit

The problem I am having is, when it asks for an additional item I put nothing I mean...I just left it blank and it prints out the statement that "Sorry we don't have  But we will change it to a gift". But what I am trying to do is, if I put nothing when it asks for an additional item then I don't print anything like "Sorry we don't have  But we will change it to a gift". I am pretty sure that I need to change the last three lines of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
for selected_additional in selected_additionals: 
    if selected_additional not in additionals and not selected_additional.strip():
        print("\nSorry we don't have "+str(selected_additional)+"\nBut we will change it to a gift")
```

This should work because Python treats empty strings as False-y.

Comment: what does the .strip() does sir?

Comment: The strip() will remove newlines, spaces and tabs from the beginning and end of the string. This ensures that if the user inputs a lot of blanks, you still don't print out the apology message.

Comment: Oh I see now why you used it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
if selected_additional not in additionals or selected_additional== " ":
```

to

```
if selected_additional not in additionals and selected_additional.strip() != "":
```

This checks that the entered item is not in your other list AND that the value entered is not blank (just white space).

This will get rid of that extra message. But if you need a certain number of inputs, you should consider asking the user for more inputs when you find an empty string.

Comment: Now how would you calculate the total price of the one available thing you picked and each additional item you picked including the gift(the gift is not free). Additional item costs $5 for each. I tried to do many things but I am really new but you seem like a senior smart engineer please help! I will pray god for you!